# How to hide a UIView that doesn't fit in available space?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uistackview

There is a stack view with 4 elements.

Every element has a Horizontal Content Compression Resistance Priority of 1000, except one:

```
A(1000) - B(1000) - C(999) - D(1000)
```

With a lot of space, there is no problem, each view takes what it needs. But, when the space is limited, the C view is the first to shrink horizontally to give space to the others.

It could shrink until is not visible:

```
A(1000) - B(1000) - - D(1000)
```

But, although invisible, the distance between B and D is twice the space between A and B. Because C has not been hidden, just shrunk.

Is there any way to detect that a view has been shrunk?, so it can be truly hidden.

PD: This view is inside a UITableViewCell, not inside a UIViewController. The cell has no didLayoutSubviews method, I tried doing this in layoutSubviews:

```objectivec
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    // Truly hide it if is not visible anymore because there is no space.
    self.view.hidden = self.view.frame.size.width == 0;
}
```

But it didn't work, any idea?

Comment: Do your 4 "elements" have fixed widths? Or are their widths dynamic? Is your stack view's width constrained? The problem is... If `C` shrinks to Zero, and you hide it - also removing the spacing - `C` will now have more space, and will no longer be Zero... so you'll show it, but that will add the additional space, so it will shrink to Zero... and you're in an infinite loop. Show how you're setting the widths of the elements. I think you may need to do some calculations rather than using a stack view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this.

[image: squashing view]

The code is given below. This is just a sample, and requires correct storyboard configuration.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint * trailingConstraint;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView             * blackView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint * blackViewTrailingConstraint;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint * blackViewWidthConstraint;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL preventLoop;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    super.viewDidLoad;

    [self.blackView addObserver:self
             forKeyPath:@"bounds"
                options:0
                context:nil];

}

- ( void ) observeValueForKeyPath: ( NSString     * ) keyPath
             ofObject: ( id             ) object
               change: ( NSDictionary * ) change
              context: ( void         * ) context
{
    if ( ! self.preventLoop ) {

        self.preventLoop = YES;

        if ( self.blackView.bounds.size.width < 10 ) {

            self.blackViewWidthConstraint.constant = 0;
            self.blackViewTrailingConstraint.constant = 0;

        } else {

            self.blackViewTrailingConstraint.constant = 40;

        }

        self.preventLoop = NO;

    }

}

- (IBAction)squashButtonAction:(id)sender {

    self.trailingConstraint.constant += 10;
    self.blackViewWidthConstraint.constant = MAX ( 0, self.blackViewWidthConstraint.constant - 10 );

}

- (IBAction)resetButtonAction:(id)sender {

    self.trailingConstraint.constant = 20;
    self.blackViewWidthConstraint.constant = 150;

}

@end
```

The idea is to use key-value observation to detect when the bounds' size goes below a threshold; 10 in this case. When that happens the relevant view (black here) will have both its width as well as its trailing constraint set to 0. The width is obvious here and the trailing constraint is the space between the black view and the last yellow view. This is so that you do not end up with double the space.

Since you change the value inside the observer, you need some logic to prevent it from looping as you can see in the code.

The black view's width constraint as well as the purple view's trailing constraint are used to simulate the squashing of the view until there is not enough space for the black view any more. In your specific case you may need to wire it up differently but this gets the job done and you have a nice working example to illustrate the idea.

**EDIT**

There are many ways to skin a cat ... here is another, even simpler idea. This mixes ideas from both your original attempt and my original answer. In stead of using an observer, you could do the same in one of the layout messages, as shown below.

I think the big difference between your attempt and what I propose is simply to add a trailing constraing (`blackViewTrailingConstraint` in my code) and then to use that to squash the trailing space to 0 at the appropriate time.

Anyhow, here is the code to accomplish the same without an observer

```
- ( void ) viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    // you could also use ...

    // if ( self.blackView.bounds.size.width < 5 ) {

    // ... here but it is more correct to use the width
    // constaint and not the actual width here as you
    // and set the constaint and the width only updates
    // once layout completes
    if ( self.blackViewWidthConstraint.constant < 5 ) {

        self.blackViewWidthConstraint.constant = 0;
        self.blackViewTrailingConstraint.constant = 0;
        
    } else {

        self.blackViewTrailingConstraint.constant = 40;

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi skaak, I can't try your code right now. I'll try next week (I'm on holiday). Thank you very much for your answer :-)

Comment: @Sergio enjoy the holiday! It is good, I've given it some thought and updated my answer.